# Can't access COM array members in WSH/JScript

Tags: .net, com, wsh, jscript

I'm trying to access the members of an array returned by a COM method from JScript through WSH on Windows 7.

The documentation for the method is as follows (given as a C# example):

```
public System.Array GetValues();
```

So according to this, it returns a .NET System.Array. This is all fine and well, but here's my code:

```
// report is Scripting.FileSystemObject file handle
// var is a COM object
arr = var.GetValues();
val = ??
report.WriteLine(val);
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
val = arr.Length      // produces empty string
val = arr.GetLength() // "Object doesn't support this property or method"
val = arr.GetValue(0) // "Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

So apparently it's not a System.Array object, because the methods don't work. Maybe it's a JScript Array object?

```
val = arr[0]          // empty string
val = arr.length      // empty string
val = arr.pop()       // "Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

So it's not an Array object either? I guess it could be an intrinsic type array:

```
val = typeof(arr[0])  // "undefined"
val = typeof(arr)     // "unknown"
```

As a last resort, I loaded it into Vbsedit and put a breakpoint there, and Vbsedit shows an array with 800 values! I just have no idea how to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probable that the array is being returned as a JScript [`VBArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y39d47w8%28VS.84%29.aspx) object. This is done because the JScript Array object is inherently very different from the SAFEARRAY structure used in COM and VBScript. You can convert the `VBArray` to a JScript array by calling the `toArray` method:

```
var jsArr = arr.toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I found the answer shortly after posting the question. Here's the solution to convert whatever type of Array "arr" is to the appropriate JScript array:

```
arr = var.GetValues().toArray();
val = arr[0];
report.WriteLine(val);
```